# How to force Firestore Recycler Adapter to load live data not from cache

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I want firestore recyclerview adapter to load data only from the server not from cache. *"I want the adapter display nothing if the device is offline."* But I don't know the way to do this and I searched for it. What I found was the way to do this in the normal `get();` method only to retrieve specific data, but I didn't find anyone to explain the way to do this with firebase firestore adapter.

that's my **MainActivity** code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FirestoreRecyclerviewAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        db=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        //Query
        Query query = db.collection("collection");
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ItemClass> options=new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ItemClass>()
                .setQuery(query, ItemClass.class)
                .build();

        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);

        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerviewAdapter( options, this );

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
```

and this is adapter class...
**Firestore Adapter**

```
public class FirestoreRecyclerviewAdapter  extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ItemClass, FirestoreRecyclerviewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    public FirestoreRecyclerviewAdapter (@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ItemClass> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ItemClass item) {
        //Binding code.

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false));
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //view components

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //initializing item components
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach I can think of is [disabling disk persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence), which you can do with:

> ```
> FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
>         .setPersistenceEnabled(false)
>         .build();
> db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
> ```

Comment: Hey, puf. Shouldn't you pass `false` to the `setPersistenceEnabled()` method, in order to disable disk persistence?

Comment: Good catch. Thanks Alex. Copy/paste/forgot-to-modify. :) I updated it now.

Comment: thanks sir, but I didn't want to prevent Persistence at all of my database.
I want to prevent the Persistence for a specific Firestore Reference which will be initialized to firestore Recyclerview adapter in It's options Query.
because this recyclerview will display some s

Comment: Because this Recyclerview will display something similar to the Vacant places on the plane can be booked.
So, I don’t want to display a place that might be reserved "This is confirmed on the server, but the user’s device hasn’t read this"

Comment: The best I can think of in that case is to use [`DocumentSnapshot.getMetadata().isFromCache()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/SnapshotMetadata). If this value is `true` the data is coming from the local cache and is not guaranteed to be up to date with the server, so you'll want to not display it in that case.

Comment: Yes, that's good. I found it by searching, but it works with a certain path and cannot be combined with the adapter Or I do not know how to implement this method in the the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Don't load/fetch data when the device has no internet connection, notify user that his/her device is offline and if want the service should make sure the device has an internet connection.